# Hibernate запрос из базы данных с помощью Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Есть 3 таблицы в базе данных MySql. Вот их классы.

**Класс родитель. Раздает id**

```
   @MappedSuperclass
public class HotelEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

public HotelEntity(Integer id){
    this.id=id;
}
public  HotelEntity(){}

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**Класс Гость**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "guest")
public class Guest extends HotelEntity{
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @JsonCreator
    public Guest(Integer id,  String name,  String surName) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surName;
    }
public Guest(){}
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "surname")
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Guest that = (Guest) o;

        if (getId() != that.getId()) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
        if (surname != null ? !surname.equals(that.surname) : that.surname != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId();
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (surname != null ? surname.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Класс услуга**

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "service")
public class Service extends HotelEntity{

    private String name;
    private Integer cost;
    private ServiceType type;

    public Service(Integer id, ServiceType type, String name, int cost) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.type = type;
    }
    public Service(){

    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "cost")
    public Integer getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(Integer cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "type")
    public ServiceType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(ServiceType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Service that = (Service) o;

        if (getId() != that.getId()) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
        if (cost != null ? !cost.equals(that.cost) : that.cost != null) return false;
        if (type != null ? !type.equals(that.type) : that.type != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId();
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (cost != null ? cost.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (type != null ? type.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str=this.getId()+this.name;
        return str;
    }
}
```

Класс с информацией о заказанной услуге и госте(id,date,guest_id,service_id)

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "guestserviceinfo")
public class GuestServiceInfo extends HotelEntity{

    private Guest guest;
    private Service service;
    private Date date;

    public GuestServiceInfo(Integer id, Guest guest, Service service, Date date) {
        super(id);
        this.guest=guest;
        this.service=service;
        this.date=date;
    }
public GuestServiceInfo(){}

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "date")
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Guest getGuest() {
        return guest;
    }
    public void setGuest(Guest guest) {
        this.guest = guest;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        GuestServiceInfo that = (GuestServiceInfo) o;

        if (getId() != that.getId()) return false;
        if (date != null ? !date.equals(that.date) : that.date != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result =(int) getId();
        result = 31 * result + (date != null ? date.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Мне нужно получить список услуг, у которых id гостя, допустим, равно 1.
Sql использовать нельзя. Только  criteria.В крайнем случае HQL.
Как это делается?

Answer (score 0):

Пишите такой метода, в который передаете сессию(как создать сессию - не предмет обусждения, поэтому считаем , что получаем ее в параметрах), а также экземпляр класса Guest, по айдишнику которого вы хотите искать.

```
public List <GuestServiceInfo > getGuestServiceInfoByGuest (Session session, Guest guest ){
    Query createQuery = session.createQuery("from GuestServiceInfo where guest = :guest"); 
                createQuery.setParameter("guest", guest); 
    List <GuestServiceInfo > guestServiceInfoList = query.list();
    return guestServiceInfoList;
    }
```

Но вообще -то, если вы юзаете хибернейт, то вы можете вытянуть данные по их связи, ведь в классе GuestServiceInfo  есть связь ManyToOne и поле типа Guest , то вполне логично , что и у класса Guest  должна быть связь OneToMany и коллекция типа GuestServiceInfo. Если обратиться к этой коллекции в пределах открытой сессии, то хибернейт по связи подтянет то, что вам надо без вских танцев с бубном. И именно этот способ является самым правильным и представляет собой соль ORM - модели.

Что касается критерии, то я не вижу смысла использовать ее в статических запросах. Слишком много кода для таких простых запросов приходится писать. Другое дело запрос динамический...

Comment: Если я получаю List<GuestServiceInfo>, то hibernate как раз и подтягивает все зависимости и объединяет в одну таблицу(судя по запросу). Но мне из этой таблицы нужен только класс "Service"(где guest_id=?). Какой по вашему правильный вариант запроса  без criteria подскажите плз?

Comment: Критерия-не панацея.Это просто средство построения запроса. Исполнитель у вас всегда один-бд. У вас есть класс Guest, у которого связь с классом GuestServiceInfo, а у GuestServiceInfo связь с Service. Ваш класс Guest ничего не знает про Service, ведь у него нет с ним связи, следовательно, и прямого запроса вы никак не построите. Исходя из этой архитектуры, вы должны получить список GuestServiceInfo, а у каждого объекта этого типа есть поле типа Service, значит одному объекту GuestServiceInfo соответсвует один объект Service. Крутите в цикле лист GuestServiceInfo и инициализируете поле Service

Comment: представьте ниточку с узелками. узедки - ваши классы, а ниточка - связь. от узелка может исходить много ниточек, но подтянуть можно только ближайший узелок, а через него те узелки, к которым уже от него непосредственно ведет ниточка. перепрыгнуть через узелок никак не получится. для этого добавьте еще одну связь.но в свете добавления связей становится весьма сомнительной ваша архитектура... у вас между гостем и сервисом есть какая-то прослойка, назначение которой быть прослойкой для подтягивания сервисов. как-то бредово звучит...